# Read and Display Ical (ics) on flutterflow

Tags: icalendar, flutterflow

I'm a beginner,
Is there any way to receive data from an iCal (ics) file and display it somehow in flutterflow?

Preferably on a calendar. Any idea?

Sorry, I have no idea how to do it, so I'm asking without having an implementation attempt.